# How to get CSGO gamestate integration data with vb.net

Tags: python, vb.net, steam

I have been writing python code for quite some time to get CSGO gamestate_integration, but I currently need to write something in vb.net to do the same thing and it's not working.

tl;dr version: vb.net won't accept the post request from CSGO, but a simple python script can echo the post request to vb.net and it works.  The vb.net application IS being run as administrator.

I have a simple class file (obviously my URIs are private):

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.ServiceModel
Imports System.ServiceModel.Web
Imports JSONReceiver

<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface iJSONReceiver
    <OperationContract>
    <WebGet()>
    Function get_stats(ByVal data As String) As String

    <OperationContract()>
    <WebInvoke(RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)>
    Function post_stats(ByVal request As Stream) As String
End Interface

Public Class JSONReceiver
    Implements iJSONReceiver

    Public Function post_stats(ByVal request As Stream) As String Implements iJSONReceiver.post_stats
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(request)
        Console.WriteLine("In post_stats")
        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd())
        Console.WriteLine()
        Return "OK"
    End Function

    Public Function get_stats(ByVal data As String) As String Implements iJSONReceiver.get_stats
        Console.WriteLine("In get_stats")
        Console.WriteLine(data)
        Console.WriteLine()
        Return "OK"
    End Function
End Class
```

And simple code to test it:

```
Public host As WebServiceHost
Public post_ep As ServiceEndpoint

Public Sub main()
    host = New WebServiceHost(GetType(JSONReceiver), New Uri("http://192.168.1.102:8080"))
    post_ep = host.AddServiceEndpoint(GetType(iJSONReceiver), New WebHttpBinding(), "")

    host.Open()
    Console.WriteLine("Press enter to quit...")
    Console.ReadLine()
    host.Close()
End Sub
```

I can use a web browser to point to the get_stats() endpoint, and it works just fine, but I am trying to use CSGOs gamestate_integration functionality to post the data to my service, and it just doesn't seem to like it.

So what I did was ripped my old python code to simply echo the request to the vb.net web service, it it works... the python code receives the data and simply posts it to the vb.net service, and the vb.net service happily accepts it.

So I change the URI for the vb JSONReceiver to port 8081, and run this script on the original uri (192.168.1.102:8080)

```
import web
import urllib2

class Stats(object):
    def POST(self):
        json_data = web.data()
        try:
            echo(json_data)
        except Exception, e:
            print(e.__str__())
        return "OK"

def echo(data):
    request = urllib2.Request("http://192.168.1.102:8081/post_stats")
    request.add_data(data)
    f = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    print f.read()


urls = (
    '/post_stats', 'Stats',
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

In short, the URI CSGO is using to post to my service is http://192.168.1.102:8080, which hits my python service, which then echoes the request verbatim to http://192.168.1.102:8081 (again, these are private URIs).

I don't know why, but it works... but having to run a wrapper to get this data is not only weird, it's really not an acceptable solution to the problem... obviously vb.net is handling post requests just fine when it's coming from my python script; obviously CSGO is posting requests correctly, or my python script wouldn't be able to receive it, so I'm having a problem finding the disconnect...

Is Python adding something to the request that CSGO might not be?

Do I need to fall back to socket programming?

Comment: Did you try first as localhost:8080?

Comment: While I'm writing this it's not on the localhost (I'm just playing back a demo on my laptop while developing on my desktop).  As I mentioned, the python script works, and I am running the vb application as administrator, so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: I can confirm I have been running it successfully on localhost, I just can't get it when it's coming externally (to the actual IP address, not 127.0.0.1).  So the python script is running on the local box, happily accepting the outside data and echoing to 127.0.0.1.  Why can't my .Net application take it directly?